# Generating synonyms using pyDictionary

Tags: python

I would like to return all the synonyms for a particular word using pyDictionary. However, I can only retrieve the first five synonyms. for example;

```
>>>from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
>>>dictionary=PyDictionary()
>>>dictionary.synonym("beautiful")
>>>[u'alluring', u'cute', u'fascinating', u'magnificent', u'marvelous']
```

Extended  list
`[u'alluring', u'cute', u'fascinating', u'magnificent', u'marvelous', 'delicate', 'dazzling', 'delightful', 'elegant','fascinating' etc]`. 
See thesaurus for the full list as pyDictionary uses Thesaurus.

Any idea on how to retrieve the complete list of synonyms for a word? and besides WordNet, are they any other recommended lexical databases for synonym generation that can be used with python?

Thanks.

Comment: If pyDictionary uses Thesaurus why can't you?

Comment: @martineau, an API is required, and I don't know how to...pyDictionary is a handy python module that one can easily install an use. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the implementation and use something similar yourself, it's only a few lines.

Comment: Read the pyDictionary source code and find out the API being used. For that matter, you could just remove the limitation from pyDictionary...

Comment: @jonrsharpe and Martineau, thanks for your suggestions, I'll look up the API